# Application supports iTunes file sharing doesn't support to App Groups container?

Tags: ios, itunes, file-sharing, ios-app-group

Can we support file sharing for App Groups path

e.g

```
 #define APP_GROUP_PATH [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"group.xxx.xxx"] path]
```

with the help of following flag?

> Application supports iTunes file sharing

I want my files to show into iTunes app which are located in app groups shared container.